# How do I use the spread operator to replace a value in an array

Tags: javascript, ngrx-store

I have the following object:

```
const initialState = {
cart: {
    products: []
},
numberOfItems: 0
```

}

In the following function, I want to replace the quantity of one of the products in the products array.

"newItems" is the object containing the changed quantity.

```
on(increaseItemQuantity, (state, action) => {
    const newItems = increaseQuantity(state, action.itemId, action.size);

    const newState  = {
        ...state,
        ...state.cart,
        products: [...newItems]
    }

    return newState;
}),
```

I expect the products array within the cart to contain an object with the new quantity, instead a new products array is created within the state.

The starting cart looks like this:

```
{
    cart:
        products: [
            {quantity: 9, size: 'XX-Large', _id: '61814f61efae17ff8c7d7a2c'},
            {quantity: 1, size: 'Medium', _id: '618152d8fe84f566364585f0'}
        ]
}
```

I want the item showing quantity 9 to be replaced with the one showing quantity 10 below:

```
{
cart:
    products: [
        {quantity: 10, size: 'XX-Large', _id: '61814f61efae17ff8c7d7a2c'},
        {quantity: 1, size: 'Medium', _id: '618152d8fe84f566364585f0'}
    ]
}
```

Instead an additional product array is added to the newState as shown below and the original in cart is never replaced:

```
newState 
  cart:
      products: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
     _id: "617046de3eaaaa7221c1924e"
  products: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(7)]




const increaseQuantity = (state, itemId, size) => {
    console.log('state.cart.products', state.cart.products)
    const item = state.cart.products.find(item => item._id === itemId && 
        item.size === size);

    const newItem = {...item};

    ++newItem.quantity;

    let  newItems = state.cart.products.filter(item => item._id !== 
          itemId   && item.size !== size);

    newItems.push(newItem);

    return newItems;
}
```

Comment: *The starting cart looks like this:* isn't valid syntax... is the `products` meant to be in an object which is `cart`'s value?

Comment: The problem here is not syntax. I am simply showing what the cart looks like.

Comment: I know it's not the problem you're facing, but it's not so clear to us what the structure is given the invalid syntax. Don't want to come up with a solution only to be told later that the actual structure is different (that sort of thing happens so, so often on SO...)

Comment: Do you have anything else in your cart other than products? If not why not make `cart` an array? It would make your code/state updates simpler.

Comment: I cut and pasted the initial cart and the resulting values from the developer console  as shown exactly. If we can get passed the issue of syntax, we can clearly see what the content of the cart is before and after processing. The problem I am trying to address is within the function shown that has no syntax error. Or we can just forget the whole thing.

Comment: @Andy, cart has other fields not just products.

Comment: why dont you try filtering out the unrequited items  first  and merge it with required like

const filtered = array.filter(x=>x.id===1)
const newArr  = [...array ,  {id : 1 , val : ""}]

Comment: @Faizal, I did the filtering in the increaseQuantity  function. I have added that function to my original question.

Comment: @Fazal, newItems has the correct values.

Comment: Try removing ...state from  
 const newState  = {
        ...state,
        ...state.cart,
        products: [...newItems]
    }

Comment: @Faizal: But I want the entire state to be returned to subscribers. If I remove the ...state, only the ...state.cart would be returned.

Comment: that is what causing your array to get duplicated

Comment: But removing ...state with ...state.cart would cause all other values in the state to be excluded and would only return the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding and filtering it might be easier to just `map` over the array, and if the product id matches a search id update the quantity value of that product object, and return it, otherwise just return an unchanged object.

You can then update your state. This creates a new state object, preserves the old state, adds a new property for the cart, preserves the properties of the existing cart, and then adds the new `updatedArray` to `products`.

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: {
    ...state.cart,
    products: updated
  }
};
```

```js
const state={cart:{products:[{quantity:9,size:"XX-Large",_id:"61814f61efae17ff8c7d7a2c"},{quantity:1,size:"Medium",_id:"618152d8fe84f566364585f0"}],anotherProp1:1,anotherProp2:2}};

function updateItem(state, id) {

  const { products } = state.cart;

  const updated = products.map(product => {
    if (product._id === id) {
      return { ...product, quantity: product.quantity + 1 };
    }
    return product;
  });

  return {
    ...state,
    cart: {
      ...state.cart,
      products: updated
    }
  };

}

const id = '61814f61efae17ff8c7d7a2c';

const updatedState = updateItem(state, id);

console.log(updatedState);
```